# Parsing an HTML from desktop with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Lets say I need to charge information from this 
website:
http://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_ValorCuotaDetalle_V2.aspx?in_ac_pre_ope=A&in_ad_fecha=31/01/2017

But as I am having problems with proxies what i've done is copying the source code from the web and pasted it on a notepad file named as test222.html.

I want to read it with beautiful soup in order to manipulate it but I dont really know how to do it. The test222.html document is on my desktop. 
All the code I have for now is this...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_parsed = 'C:/Users/Desktop/test222.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_parsed, 'html.parser')

print soup
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` expects an HTML string, so you need to read the file first:

```
with open(r'C:/Users/Desktop/test222.html') as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
print soup
```